# How to generate a List of BigDecimals in Kotlin without a loop?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I want to create a List of BigDecimals in Kotlin

```
[ 0.0, 0.1 .. 9.9 ]
```

How can I achieve the following without a loop?

```
val numbers: List<BigDecimal> = generateNumbers()

fun generateNumbers(): List<BigDecimal> {
    val list = ArrayList<BigDecimal>()
    for (i in 0..9)
        (0..9).mapTo(list) { BigDecimal("$i.$it") }

    return list
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do that with [`.flatMap { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html), which concatenates the resulting lists into one:

```
fun generateNumbers(): List<BigDecimal> = 
    (0..9).flatMap { i -> 
        (0..9).map { 
            BigDecimal("$i.$it") 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create the required list of BigDecimals, when you know in advance the number of elements and the formula mapping index to element, is following:

```
val numbers = List(100) { index -> BigDecimal(index).scaleByPowerOfTen(-1) }
```

Here we create a list of 100 elements where each element is derived from its index (which is in range 0..99) scaled by 10<sup>-1</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how much you want to add per step (e.g. `0.1`), you could also use [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) instead:

```
val yourSequence = generateSequence(BigDecimal.ZERO) { 
    it + BigDecimal("0.1")
}.takeWhile { it < BigDecimal.TEN }
```

Afterwards you can call something like `yourSequence.forEach(::println)` if you like.

If you want an infinite sequence instead, just skip the `takeWhile`, e.g. the following suffices:

```
generateSequence(BigDecimal.ZERO) { 
    it + BigDecimal("0.1")
}
```

Applying it to a function ("formatted" so that everything is immediately visible):

```
fun generateNumbers(from: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO,
                    uptoExclusive: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.TEN,
                    step: BigDecimal = BigDecimal("0.1")
                    ) = generateSequence(from) {  it + step }
                            .takeWhile { it < uptoExclusive }
```

Sample usage:

```
generateNumbers().forEach(::println)
generateNumbers(BigDecimal.ONE, step = BigDecimal.ONE).forEach(::println)
```